# Display words in color

Tags: command-line, sed, grep

I am looking for a tool which takes a file in input and a word to search. It should display the file with color the words if it corresponds to the search.

Like `grep --colors` but displays all the file.

Is there something already exists ?

Example : `cat /etc/passwd | colors root`
Display all /etc/passwd file and color the words "root"

If I can change the color easily it would be great !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little trick with grep will do the job:

```
grep --color "^\|root" /etc/passwd
```

Otherwise look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267400/colour-highlighting-output-based-on-regex-in-shell/4269167#4269167).

Comment: Super ! I didn't find these entries ! Thanks a lot